# XSS inside JavaScript string literal without single quotes?

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript

As a pentester I came across this scenario:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 URL = 'http://example.com?x=input';
```

I am able to insert a new line with `%A0`, spaces and almost anything except `'`. The problem is that I need that `'` before making a new line so the JS doesn't break.

I am able to leave it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 URL = 'http://example.com?x=input;
 prompt`9`
 anything';
```

After the input and before the `;` I need to insert a `'` or it won't work... Is there any workaround/bypass on this? I am able to inset `/` too.

Comment: Have you tried using web encoded characters like %27 for ' or sending as binary?

Comment: yes i have tried using %27 and double encoding, however i didn't try binary... i never thought that encoding would work in this scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not XSSable.

(I'm assuming in your scenario angle brackets are blacklisted too. Otherwise, you could obviously close the script tag with `</script>` and inject a separate script that doesn't use single quotes.)

In JS/ES syntax, a string literal that starts with a single quote needs to be ended with a single quote. Since you can't inject one yourself, you may at most cause a syntax error by introducing unescaped line breaks or escaping the closing single quote with a `\`. An attacker could use that to prevent execution of the current script which may eventually be chained with other bugs to something more severe. But it's not XSS-exploitable by itself.

Comment: Yes they are! thanks for letting me know. learning where the dead ends are is useful for future websites i test. thank you.

Comment: However, it is still exploitable (not as XSS) because you literally break JS code by making a new line. In the case previously explained i just broke an entire functionality of the website.

Comment: @Mr.ToxicMan Sure, *"you may at most cause a syntax error"*. This *may* be helpful in some attack scenarios, but it's certainly not XSS-exploitable.