# XSS inside of a javascript string, with unusual filter

Tags: php, xss, javascript

While making a website I made an interesting mistake, and I'm wondering if this could be used to achieve XSS. I've come very close, but not quite.
I can put my user input into a string inside of a `<script>` tag. It looks something like this:

```
<script>
// some code above
some_variable = "my user input"
// some code below
</script>
```

I intended to escape `"` and `\` characters, by putting a backslash in front of them. I also completely remove any newlines.
But accidentally I put a normal slash instead of a backslash. So I only escaped the `"` and `/` characters.
This means I can escape the string with something like `\"` which will turn into `\\"` and break me out of the string.
Normally you would simply do `\"-alert(1)//` to escape the string, execute the alert and then comment out the rest of the code. But since in my unique example I escaped the `/` character, you can't comment out the rest with that.
To make it more clear here is an example:

```
// Common example
some_variable = "\\"-alert(1)//"
// My situation
some_variable = "\\"-alert(1)\/\/"
```

Lots of things I've tried already all result in some sort of syntax error, which doesn't execute the code. I'm wondering if there is some sort of trick I missed to still get XSS from this.

This question is similar to [XSS inside JavaScript string literal without single quotes?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220551/xss-inside-javascript-string-literal-without-single-quotes), which isn't exploitable. But here I can actually get out of the string without using newlines, maybe that makes a difference.

Here is the exact PHP code that resulted in this problem:

```
function toSafeJavascript($unsafe) {
    $safe = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), '', $unsafe); // Remove newlines
    $safe = preg_replace('/([\\/"])/', '\\\\$1', $safe);

    return $safe;
}
```

Comment: `</script><svg onload=alert()><script>` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neat puzzle! **Yes**, that filter is exploitable.

### Attack

For historical reasons, ECMAScript (aka Javascript) supports an extended syntax when run in a web browser context. One syntax feature is the parsing of an HTML comment (`<!-- foo -->`) like a regular JS comment (`/* foo */`) as long as it does not span over multiple lines. (See [B.1.1 HTML-like Comments](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-html-like-comments) of the spec.)

So, given the injection context...

```
<script>
x = "<?php echo toSafeJavascript($unsafe); ?>"
</script>
```

...and your filter function (which backslash-escapes `"` and `/` and removes newlines), the following attack vector triggers XSS:

```
\";prompt('gimme bounty')<!--
```

Here, the filter generates this valid JS code:

```
x = "\\";prompt('gimme bounty')<!--"

|-------||--------------------||----|
 string         payload        comment
 assignment
```

### Defense

*Never* implement a filter for a common use case yourself. Even if you're certain the implementation is correct, anyone auditing the code will have to spend some extra time following the regex and replacement logic.

Also *don't* print user data within inline `<script>` code. The nested contexts make proper escaping more complicated. As I proposed [in this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/254690/95381), consider storing dynamic data in an HTML [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attribute and retrieve it from static JS later.

If you still want to stick to the PHP-within-JS approach, consider a built-in function like [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (with the proper flags!) as suggested [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110110/95381).

Comment: Very cool solution! I totally forgot about still being able to use HTML tags. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @J0R1AN Thanks, just to be clear: It's not actually an HTML comment. You couldn't use arbitrary HTML tags within the script block. Semantically, it's a simple JS comment. It's an explicit JS syntax feature rather than a consequence of using an HTML comment.

Comment: This solution is awesome.